# ASP.NET UPDATE PANEL GETS INVISIBLE

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've a web form with some registration details.  I've a submit button in a update panel on the same page.  If the user doesn't enter anything and clicks on submit button, it should do validation on all the mandatory fields of the form and display a message showing what fields are missing.

As soon as enter submit button with out entering anything, it is doing validation but throwing an execption:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could
>   not find UpdatePanel with ID
>   'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Content_UpdatePanel_Submit'. If it is being
>   updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.

and my update panel with submit button becomes invisible.  The code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_Submit" runat="server" UpdateMode='conditional'>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="font-size: 12pt; width: 938px; margin-top: 5px; border-top: ridge 2px gray;">
                <div style="margin-top: 10px; width: 938px;">

                    <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server"  ToolTip="Click here to submit your request." 
                    Text='Submit Request' onclick="btn_submit_Click" />

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_cancel" runat="server" ToolTip=''>Cancel</asp:LinkButton></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What do I do to prevent my update panel from going invisible?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy: In the spirit of the OP's title, I think your comment should read: SHOW SERVER CODE :)

Answer (score 0):

With [UpdateMode Conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx), you either need to add [ChildAsTriggers=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx) or add a [Asyncpostback trigger](http://ramanisandeep.net/2009/04/07/asyncpostbacktrigger-vs-postbacktrigger/) to that button

Few Examples:

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/11/ajax-updatepanel-how-to-use-updatemode.html

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-updatemode-of-the-updatepanel

Comment: I tested again after adding ChildrenAsTriggers = "True". It didn't work